# Android - Open url in external browser causes an infinite loop

Tags: android, android-intent

My app can open links by default using this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="example.com"    
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:scheme="http" />
             ....
```

Now, I have a link in my app that **I do not support (yet)**. So what I am doing in the meanwhile is open it with an external browser. like this:

```
String requestURL = "www.example.com/unsupportedlink";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(requestURL));
mActivity.startActivity(i);
```

What I expect is that it will be open on the browser, but if the user chose that all links will be opened by app by default ("Allways open" and not "Just Once"), the app is called again and sends the link to the browser again - it causes infinite loop.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: have you tried using a valid site like google.com or something ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it with the right url

Comment: You put it directly for example in me app i no create "data" in mi XML `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.es")));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I found the answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755650/588532)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(requestURL);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```