# Launching a browser from native android app

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am launching a browser for authentication purpose from my native android app. Does anyone know any example apps which do this similar stuff? Also what are the pros or cons with this approach?

Comment: Use a Webview in your application.

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332868/open-the-native-browser-from-an-android-app if you want to open the browser. Alternatively, you can use WebView to display the webpage from inside of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the **android API Demos, in the section Views, and then WebView** there is an example of what you need to know to launch the browser.

The pros and cons are maybe that it will be easier to implement authentication in a separate website depending on your skills and current knowledge, but I would definitely use the Android LoginActivity as I said in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490283/how-to-send-a-response-back-to-native-android-app/25644868#25644868) similar question.

Doing it natively will provide you with more control over your App and also will improve your Android skills, which is a really good thing!